# Connecting or disconnecting a cable

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a single word that can describe the process of connecting or disconnecting a cable to a testing machine. This concerns the name of a function in a software program I am working on. The function accepts a true/false value which indicates to the user if they should connect or disconnect a specific cable.
Currently I have called it `MoveCable()` but this isn't an ideal name for it. I also want to avoid a name such as `ConnectDisconnectCable()`. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is "attach" and "detach", but I don't know of any word that could mean either. What purpose would the word serve if people didn't know whether it meant on or off? You could do `CableConnected` or `ConnectCable` yes/no.

Comment: @TimRomano It's not so much the word, but the name of a process, the outcome of which should be known to the user before initiating it. I understand it's for Java Programming language.

Comment: If it is an *instruction* to the user:   `ConnectCable: yes` or `ConnectCable: no`.

Comment: @TimRomano The user sees a nice message - "Connect the cable" - so this magic word is only for the programmers. When I write `MoveCable(true)` in my code I know that the program expects the user to connect the cable, likewise `MoveCable(false)` means to disconnect. During code review someone didn't like the word "Move".

Comment: @AndySemyonov C# but close enough ;)

Comment: In that case, I'm voting you down, because this site is not about how to write self-documenting code.  You want 'connectCable': e.g. `ConnectCable(true)`.

Comment: @TimRomano does it matter if it's for code or not? I am just wondering if there's a word that describes the *process* of moving a cable such that it connects or disconnects. A simple "no, there is no word to describe this" is more helpful than a downvote.

Comment: `ConnectCable(bool)`  The verb 'connect' normally means the processing of attaching, but in a programming context, the boolean parameter can signify 'disconnect' when set to false.  (The downvote is to signal that this question is not of general interest for those who are interested in the English language).

Comment: @valsidalv Well I have used a little bit of C# and I found it's syntax were very similar to that of Java Programming.

Comment: How about SetConnectionState()

Comment: It's a good question and should not be down-voted. Outside of code, is there such a word? With a switch, we can say "toggle", whether the switch is currently set to on or off.

Comment: I'd separate it into two methods, Connect() and Disconnect().

Comment: I've been in the computer business for over 40 years, and I've never heard terms other than "connect"/"attach"/"plug" and "disconnect"/"detach"/"unplug" (unless you want to go with something like "hook up" and "unhook").  For your situation, though, you could use a word such as "configure" or "reconfigure".  Or, from the old plugboard era, you could go with the word "patch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really about English Language, but about computing practice.

When naming variables, clarify is the most important thing, far above brevity. With modern IDEs you only ever have to type a function name once - the auto-suggestion system will regenerate it all the other times. SO even if you found a short but obscure word that meant 'to connect or disconnect', using it would undoubtedly be more confusing. Assuming that the intention is that calling the function causes the cable to be changed from connected to disconnected or vica versa:

- setConnectedState(boolean)

is your best bet or

- setCableConnectedState(boolean)
  if it isn't obvious from context what is being connected.
- setConnected(boolean) (or setCableConnected(boolean))

would also work.

- setConnectedOrDisconnected(boolean)

is clearer about what is being changed, but it isn't immediately obvious which way 'true' and 'false' are to be interpreted.

Comment: I like `SetCableState()` or `SetCableConnectedState()`. I guess if there was a word to "toggle" a cable the same way we can toggle a switch someone would have mentioned it by now.

Answer (score 0):

How about CableConnectionStatus() or CableStatus() or ConnectionStatus() ?